# How to handle Spring Websockets (stomp) with balanced multi-sever

Tags: tomcat, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, multiserver

I have a single tomcat server with a Spring application with Stomp.

It uses websockets to notify to subscriber clients some events.

[image]

I would like **to move the server structure to a balanced multi-server**, but my question is: what will happend to websocket clients? They will be notified only by their server!

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Is there something already developed to solve this scenario?

Comment: You need to store event from client somewhere. Maybe Kafka? On event occurence each of ws-server would read it and broadcast to appropriate clients.

Comment: But is not possibile to let servers listen each other to topic and relay messages? I was wondering if it is so uncommon to face this problem.

Comment: It's possible using spring WebSocketStompClient and communicate through web sockets but it's not the best solution. I'd recommend message broker.

Comment: How a message broker can solve the problem? Is it not the same problem, the message will be processes by one server and the reply will be sent only to attached clients, am I wrong?

Comment: Each of ws server would be client of message broker.